# Kotlin interface implementation breaks `equals` overriding

Tags: inheritance, kotlin, operator-overloading, operators

I have the following class that acts as a base for a few other classes:

```
abstract class BaseFitness: Comparable<BaseFitness> {
    var valid: Boolean = false
    fun invalidate() { valid = false }
    abstract fun value(): Double
    abstract fun copy(): BaseFitness

    override operator fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean =
        if (other is BaseFitness)
            this.value() == other.value()
        else
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Can only compare to another class derived from BaseFitness.")

    override fun compareTo(other: BaseFitness): Int =
        this.value().minus(other.value())
            .let { if (it.isNaN()) 0.0 else it }
            .sign.toInt()

    @JvmName("compareToOperator")
    operator fun compareTo(other: Any?): Int =
        if (other is BaseFitness)
            this.compareTo(other)
        else
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Can only compare to another class derived from BaseFitness.")
}
```

Now in this class I want to implement basic comparison behaviour.

Basically I want to be able to do:

1. `if (fit1 == fit2) { /* do stuff */ }`
2. `if (fit1 > fit2) { /* do stuff */ }`
3. `if (fit1 < fit2) { /* do stuff */ }`
4. `myFitnessSequence.max()`

The `equals()` and `compareTo()` operator funcs take care of the first 3 items. However for the last item I need `BaseFitness` to implement `Comparable`. Problem is that when I implement comparable and add the non-operator `compareTo()` method somehow `equals()` breaks with this message:

```
'operator' modifier is inapplicable on this function: must override ''equals()'' in Any
```

I tried doing the same thing I did with `compareTo()`, just having 2 implementations of `equals()`, one marked as an operator and one left as a method and adding `@JvmName` to one of them and I get

```
'@JvmName' annotation is not applicable to this declaration
```

Right now my options are basically to either choose to keep and `==` operator but not implement `Comparable` or give up `==` to use comparable.

Comment: Your `equals` implementation breaks the contract. It should be safe to compare it to anything (and simply return false for other types of objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to mark `equals` and `compareTo` with the `operator` keyword, both of these are already defined as operator in their respective types.
In case of `equals`, `Any` defines it as `operator` and the `compareTo` is marked as `operator` in `Comparable` `interface`.

So all you have to do is provide their implementation by overriding them.

From [Kotlin in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action)

> ***Regarding the equals method***
>
> The equals function is marked as override, because, unlike other
> conventions, the method implementing it is defined in the Any class
> (equality comparison is supported for all objects in Kotlin). That
> also explains why you don’t need to mark it as operator: the base
> method in Any is marked as such, ***and the operator modifier on a method
> applies also to all methods that implement or override it***.
>
> ***Regarding the Comparable interface***
>
> Kotlin supports the same Comparable interface. But the compareTo
> method defined in that interface can be called by convention, and uses
> of comparison operators ('<',
> '>', <=, and >=) are translated into calls of compareTo.